Where does the Product Version of a file's properties come from?
(This is difficult to search for, as when you look for "Windows Product Version", you get a lot of results pertaining to the OS and not of a file)
I am building stuff in VS2022, and want to control the version numbers.  After I generate something (in this case a dll), I can right-click on it (in Win10 in this case), select properties, I see the following:

I understand where the "File version" comes from in my VS2022 project.  But where does the "Product version" come from?

It all comes from the VS_VERSION_INFO PE resource. If you're using VisualC++ then you control this via your .rc files. If you're using C# then you're limited to the various [assembly:  ] attributes like AssemblyVersionAttribute, AssemblyFileVersionAttribute, and AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute. Note that Windows Explorer File Properties has not displayed those attributes' data consistently over time.

I'm using c#, so it sounds like you're saying that this is an effectively abandoned property when it comes to c#?  (And I can't control it from VS)

Actually I take that last bit back.  I got it to propagate via the VS2022 project's "Package Version"

In poking around, I discovered that by manually setting the "PackageVersion" in the project's properties, I could set what was reported in the "Product Version" in  Windows explorer.
The default version of the PackageVersion is:

But this confused me as I had not set "VersionPrefix" in my project.  When searching online for that symbol, I encountered this question1:
Setting the version number for .NET Core projects - CSPROJ - not JSON projects
In which the accepted answer states:

If Version is unset, use VersionPrefix (defaults to 1.0.0 if unset)
and - if present - append VersionSuffix.

And in circling back to my project where I manually set the PackageVersion to be "1.2.0", I discovered that VS had inserted this into the csproj file:
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <Version>1.2.0</Version>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

So mystery solved, but Microsoft's naming policies didn't help.

1. IMHO my question is almost, but not a dupe of that other question.

Oh Peter, I went insane trying to find the same information. But I found a simpler solution, hence sharing the same as it might be useful - Set the AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute to what you want and that is Product Version in the Windows explorer, assembly properties -> Product Version.
